# Using inheritance from concrete class to implement pure virtual method C++

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

I want to implement the pure virtual methods from an interface using the implementation
provided by an concrete class without having to call explicitly the method from the concrete class. Example:

```
class InterfaceA{  
public:  
    virtual void foo() = 0;  
};

class InterfaceB:public InterfaceA{  
public:  
   virtual void bar() = 0;  
};

class ConcreteA : public InterfaceA{  
public:  
   virtual void foo(){}//implements foo() from interface  
};

class ConcreteAB: public InterfaceB, public ConcreteA{  
public:  
    virtual void bar(){}//implements bar() from interface  
};
```

In this scenario, the compiler asks for a implementation of foo() in class ConcreteAB, because InterfaceB does not have it implemented and it inherited from InterfaceA.

There is a way to tell the compiler to use the implementation from ConcreteA without using a wrapper calling ConcreteA::foo()?

Comment: The code seems fine: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2W44n2$3

Comment: Once I add the `;` you're missing, this compiles fine on g++ 4.5. Can you show us the real code that's causing the problem?

Comment: I don't want to do this. I want to tell the compiler that the implementation is provided from ConcreteA without using a wrapper/stub. There is a way?

Comment: http://ideone.com/aN0Eam - you have a buggy compiler.

Comment: paste error message you are getting

Comment: The code you have here works just fine. You're going to have to be clearer about the problem you think you have.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to inherit InterfaceA in InterfaceB

Comment: Why is `InterfaceB` a child of `InterfaceA` in the first place? This seems like a design smell to me.

Comment: Mark , i Want to use polymorphic behavior using InterfaceB, so I have to inherit from InterfaceA to use methods from interfaceA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `InterfaceA` a virtual base class.

```
class InterfaceB : public virtual InterfaceA {  
public:  
   virtual void bar() = 0;  
};

class ConcreteA : public virtual InterfaceA {  
public:  
   virtual void foo(){}//implements foo() from interface  
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need [virtual inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-inheritance-where.html).

Interface A, at the top of the hierarchy, should be inherited virtually by all immediate subclasses.

```
class InterfaceB:public virtual InterfaceA{  
public:  
   virtual void bar() = 0;  
};

class ConcreteA : public virtual InterfaceA{  
public:  
   virtual void foo(){}//implements foo() from interface  
};
```